# How to move tick labels in horizontal bar chart?

Tags: d3.js

I've created a horizontal bar chart in d3 and I'm trying to implement a sort function to order both the bars and their corresponding labels. The chart so far looks like this:
[image: bar chart]

Clicking on the "Sort" button sorts the bars properly, but doesn't move the labels.

The data for chart looks like this

```
const data = [
      {
        COL_DIV_CODE: 'Academic Affairs',
        avg_base: 67778.9,
      },
      {
        COL_DIV_CODE: 'Finance and Administration',
        avg_base: 75000.1,
      },
      {
        COL_DIV_CODE: 'Arts and Humanities, College of',
        avg_base: 68109.0,
      },
    ];
```

Here's a full demo of the code so far: [bl.ocks.org](https://bl.ocks.org/sa7mon/dc4bec2951c8ac9bf3c9fc6ef6c268e6)

Specifically this part:

```
d3.select("#byValue").on("click", function() {
    data.sort(function(a,b) {
        return d3.descending(a.avg_base, b.avg_base);
    });

    yScale.domain(data.map(function(d) {
        return d.avg_base;
    })); 

    // Move bars
    svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .attr("y", function(d, i) {
            console.log("bar: ", d.avg_base, " ", yScale(d.avg_base));
            return yScale(d.avg_base);
        });

    // Move bar labels 
    svg.selectAll(".bar-label")
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .attr("y", function(d) {
            var obj = findObjectByCollegeName(d, data);
            return yScale(obj.COL_DIV_CODE) + yScale.bandwidth() / 2 - 8;
        });         
});
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, try not to manually change nodes that you didn't create yourself -- namely axis labels. Usually, the proper approach is to select the container you applied axis to, and just use the `call(axis)` on it again.

Secondly, there isn't a real reason for you to change the domain field for the scale; you *do* need to reapply it because the order changed, but you can reuse `COL_DIV_CODE`. Particularly important, because it seems axis uses the field to identify labels before and after the change (`call(axis)`).

Some minor things -- use alternatives to `attr` where available, since it always overwrites everything, when sometimes you might want to only change parts. I'm talking about assigning classes (use `classed`), and styles (`styled`).

Here is your bl.ocks code with minimal changes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body { margin:0;position:fixed;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="byValue">Sort by Value</button>
  <script>
    const data = [
      {
        COL_DIV_CODE: 'Academic Affairs',
        avg_base: 67778.9,
      },
      {
        COL_DIV_CODE: 'Finance and Administration',
        avg_base: 75000.1,
      },
      {
        COL_DIV_CODE: 'Arts and Humanities, College of',
        avg_base: 68109.0,
      },
    ];

    const maxObj = data.reduce(function(max, obj) {
      return obj.avg_base > max.avg_base? obj : max;
    });

    function findObjectByCollegeName(name, data) {
      for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        if (data[i].COL_DIV_CODE == name) {
          return data[i]
        }
      }
    }

        const heightMargin = 120;
        const widthMargin = 300;
    const width = 1200 - 2 * widthMargin;
    const height = 400 - 2 * heightMargin;

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", 960)
      .attr("height", 500)

    const chart = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${widthMargin}, ${heightMargin})`);

        // Draw X axis
    const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([width, 0])
        .domain([maxObj.avg_base, 0]);

    chart.append('g')
        .attr('transform', `translate(0, 0)`)
        .call(d3.axisTop(xScale));

    // Draw Y axis
    const yScale = d3.scaleBand()
        .range([0, height])
        .domain(data.map((s) => s.COL_DIV_CODE))
        .padding(0.2);

    var axisLeft = d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickFormat(function(d) {return d; });

    chart.append('g')
        .attr('transform', `translate(0, 0)`)
        .attr('class', 'y-axis')
        .call(axisLeft);

    d3.selectAll(".y-axis .tick text")
      .attr("class", "bar-label"); // Add a class to the bar labels 

    // Draw gridlines - vertical
    chart.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'grid')
        .call(d3.axisTop()
            .scale(xScale)
            .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
            .tickFormat(''));

    // // Draw bars
    chart.selectAll()
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr("class","bar")
        .attr('style', 'fill: steelblue')
        .attr('y', (s) => yScale(s.COL_DIV_CODE))
        .attr('x', 0)
        .attr('width', (s) => xScale(s.avg_base))
        .attr('height', yScale.bandwidth());

     d3.select("#byValue").on("click", function() {
      data.sort(function(a,b) {
        return d3.descending(a.avg_base, b.avg_base);
      });

        yScale.domain(data.map(function(d) {
        return d.COL_DIV_CODE;
    })); 

    // Move bars
        svg.selectAll(".bar")
            .transition()
            .duration(500)
            .attr("y", function(d, i) {
                console.log("bar: ", d.avg_base, " ", yScale(d.avg_base));
                return yScale(d.COL_DIV_CODE);
            });

    // Move bar labels 
       /*
        svg.selectAll(".bar-label")
            .transition()
            .duration(500)
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                var obj = findObjectByCollegeName(d, data);
                return yScale(obj.COL_DIV_CODE) + yScale.bandwidth() / 2 - 8;
            });     
        */

         chart.select('g.y-axis')
            .transition()
                    .duration(500)
            .call(axisLeft);

    });
  </script>
</body>
```